# SQL select with not statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table 1 as:

```
Name    Name2    Number 
asd     voe      1.00 
rt      casg     4.00 
qdef    fr       62.00 
erfr    cre      25.00 
fgf     sewq     55.50 
ytyt    dsvf     68.50 
ujer    wqw      81.50 
uyjum   vtr      94.50
```

I want to select all columns from table 1 which do not match:

```
Name2    Number 
cre      25.00 
sewq     55.50 
casg     4.00
```

i.e. my final output should be:

```
Name    Name2    Number 
asd     voe      1.00 
qdef    fr       62.00 
ytyt    dsvf     68.50 
ujer    wqw      81.50 
uyjum   vtr      94.50
```

Right now I am doing it in two stages where I use `Except` statement and temp tables.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: You mean `WHERE NOT IN (...)`?

Comment: You can't do where not in between tables with different number of columns

Comment: You sure can. You just need to select *one* column in your subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way would be `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.name2 = t1.name2 and t2.number = t1.number
                 );
```

As Hadi shows you can also write this as a `left join`.

Contrary to the comment, you can do this using `not in`, with a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.number not in (select t2.number
                        from table2 t2
                        where t2.name2 = t1.name2
                       );
```

(Other databases do support `not in` on tuples; SQL Server is not one of them.)

I strongly advocate using `not exists` or `left join`, because the above has unexpected behavior when there are `NULL` values in `table2`.

Also, this is not safe if `number` is stored as a floating point number.  This should be fine if `number` is a `decimal`/`numeric` type.

Comment: I don't know about that second one

Answer (score 2):

If the data is in another table, You can use `NOT EXISTS` (recommended)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2  AS T2 WHERE T2.NAME2 = NAME2 AND T2.NUMBER  = NUMBER)
```

Or a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.NAME2 = T2.NAME2 AND T1.NUMBER = T2.NUMBER
WHERE T2.NAME2 IS NULL
```

For more info, read [this article](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) it contains useful information on **not in vs not exists vs left join**

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing are trying to accomplish is described as an *left anti semi join* in relational algebra. If you look at the actual execution plan for each of Gordon's solutions SQL server uses the Nested Loops Anti Semi Join algorithm to filter the rows. In SQL Server you can perform an anti semi join using NOT IN and NOT EXISTS [logical operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189773.aspx) as Gordon demonstrated. If you did not need to return the Name column from table1 you could also perform an anti semi join using EXCEPT which is a [set operator](https://sql-programmers.com/set-operators-in-sql-server-union-union-all-intersect-except). The solution using EXCEPT would look like this:

```
SELECT name2, number FROM table1
EXCEPT 
SELECT name2, number FROM table2;
```

The advantage of EXCEPT over NOT EXISTS and NOT IN is cleaner code. A key disadvantage is how set operators (EXCEPT, INTERSECT and UNION [|ALL]) requires you to have an equal number of columns in each referenced table/set.